# pdb set_trace() is not working properly in spyder 3

Tags: python-2.7, debugging, spyder, pdb

When I write (at any script):

import pdb;
pdb.set_trace()

1. Sometimes when I press n+enter the program send me to "interactiveshell"
2. Other times, if pressing n+enter I can move forward, I can't no longer see what's going on with the variables that are being generated in "variables explorer" as I used to do a few days ago (even stoping completelly the debugging process)

This wasn't happen few days ago (the debugger worked properly with the same way of using), however I haven't been able to use the debugger as usual again.

Thank in advance.
Raúl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) `pdb.set_trace()` was not supported when Spyder **3.0** was released in September 2016. We didn't supported officially before that, and the fact that it was working was a matter of luck.

However, that was solved in Spyder **3.2.0**, released in July 2017.

Comment: Got it , however I use cells a lot (#%%), so when I'm debugging a a specific cell, the debugger go through of all them and not specifically to the cell that I'm debugging. In other hand , If I execute just such cell using control + enter, the debugger doesn't work, executing the whole script without taking into account the breakpoints. Is there any way to deal with this?. Finally, when I'm debugging I can't double click to access each variabe created (even when I completelly stop the debugging process), Is there any way to access them in order to check if they are being created properly?

Comment: Debugging specific cells is not supported (and I really don't know how we could ever support it. Does Matlab do it? If so, how?) About inspecting variables while debugging, that unfortunately disabled in Spyder 3.0 after a restructuring of the IPython console. We'll try to reenable it again in a couple of months.

Comment: I'll try  eclipse to find out if I can debug properly there

Comment: @CarlosCordoba, follow up question for you. One of the benefits of `pdb.set_trace()` is I could run the debug at that particular point without having to re-run the file from start. If I do set breakpoints with `F12` and then use Debug toolbars to move through the code, it has to always start from the start of the file, which I don't necessarily need it to do all the time. How can I have it go to Debug mode for a specific cell or block in my code and skip all the previous lines since the variables are already stored as needed to that point?

Comment: @chitown88, I updated the answer to reflect the current state of `pdb.set_trace()` in the Spyder.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba, thank you. However, I am on spyder version 3.3.1, and I do have the issue stated in the OP of `Sometimes when I press n+enter the program send me to "interactiveshell"` . It won't let me go line to line in my for loop that I was try to iterate through in debug mode.